# Execution failed for task ':app:javaCompileDebug'

Tags: java, android

I recently went back to an app in android studio that worked fine on Android Studio 2.3.3 but this morning when I was prompted to update to Studio 3.0 my module wont make. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding but when I try run it on my device the build fails and gives me this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following 
dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation 
processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
- androidannotations-4.0.0.jar (org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.0.0)
Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.
```

I have no clue about android annotations that is why I am asking here on SO.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I was able to find [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/908). **[This picture solved my problem!](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/13031505/25555642/0475e45a-2d27-11e7-8d9a-0ed9e0e753d8.png)**